# Trying to understand diversification in market indexes

Tags: european-union, market-indexes, diversification, standard-and-poors-500

I have read an article in `morningstar` telling that `Euro Stoxx 50` provides a good degree of diversification. This surprises me, my understanding is that the `S&P 500` is well diversified, how can an index with only 50 companies be considered as well diversified?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I don't think "a good degree of diversification" is meant to imply "as well diversified as the S&P 500".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diversification means having a variety of investments in a portfolio. Varies studies have suggested that for stocks, 25 or so of them  achieves that.

An investment in the Euro Stoxx 50 would certainly achieve a good degree of diversification. An investment in the S&P 500 would provide far more than that.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer has pointed out if you hold direct shares about 25 is enough, which prevents a huge loss if one company goes under and it minmizes the costs associated with buying and selling.  The more stocks you hold the more overheads you have, not only that you have to track the performance and dealings of many more companies.  So 50 is more than enough for even billionaires